# When referencing a view in a stored procedure query, does it get evaluated or act as a placeholder for the query text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-view, sqlperformance

If we had a query that references SQL Server views, do the views get evaluated separately (i.e. like a sub-query) or does it just get replaced by the view's query before evaluating it as a single query?

Hoping to optimize performance!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. A view is a query, it will run just like any other query. Do your views reference other views? Are you trying to fix a performance problem that doesn't exist?

Comment: No, I am trying to fix performance issues that actually exist! So, for example, if we had a query with a sub-query, I would have thought that two queries are run for the desired output. But what if we select from a view, then apply some WHERE clauses - would that mean we are running two queries or just one - if so, surely, the first query (that evaluating the view) would return more data than if we had copied the query of the view and appended the WHERE clause and run it as a single query?

Answer (score 1):

Just like a sub query a view is not evaluated separately.  The view is combined with the referencing query and optimized as a single query.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer - so, for example, if we had a query with a sub-query, I would have thought that two queries are run for the desired output. But what if we select from a view, then apply some WHERE clauses - would that mean we are running two queries or just one - if so, surely, the first query (that evaluating the view) would return more data than if we had copied the query of the view and appended the WHERE clause and run it as a single query?

Comment: The WHERE clause will be pushed all the way to the base tables, unless the query prevents it by wrapping the base table columns in expressions.  Subqueries, views and CTEs all behave the same here.  If you want to explicitly run the view or subquery first, you can use it to load a temp table.

Comment: ok, thank you so much for your time and response - really appreciate it!